# Kindle Not showing up and backup not converting in Droid Explorer. Titanium Backup also not working

Tags: titanium-backup, droid-explorer

So I had to get my Kindle 10" replaced, so I created two backup's. One in Droid Explorer and one in Titanium Backup. Titanium Backup wont see the files for some reason, and now Droid Explorer won't read my Kindle. It see's my kindle, but it doesn't show the file system, nor will my back up convert to a basic backup.

Am I missing something? I'm rooted, everything installed as before but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

ADB wasn't given proper root permission, so it wasn't seeing the device's file structure. As for the backup, I made a copy of the abex file in to my adb folder (probably irrelevant where), then tried converting it again and it worked. With the .ab file however, Droid Explorer crashes when trying to run the restore, but it ran fine with running the command manually. adb restore .ab.

Comment: ::disclaimer: i am the developer of droidexplorer:: I was going to suggest the permissions. Glad you got it sorted out. With the ABEX file, you would not have been able to restore that one directly, because the ABEX is directly tied to a specific device. the crash, i will file an issue on that and investigate it. Thank you, glad you got it working.